# Do native English speakers pronouce b as m?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, abbreviations, pronunciation-vs-spelling, conversation

I very often study English and try to improve my listening skill with some educational materials. And I just encountered a sentence, "Once he made an alarm clock for cats – you know, to wake the**m** up from their naps." However, the speaker speaks the last part of this sentence as follows, "tweikthe**b**a^(p)from". That sounded very weird to me, since I thought she should've probably pronounced like "tweikthe**m**a^(p)from" in place of "**b**a". So I once sounded exactly like her and spoke it to the Google Translate app, and, surprisingly, it worked and translate **b** to **m**.

ex. I will wake the**m** up from their naps.

aiwoweikthe**b**a^from

So my question is that do native English speakers sometimes pronounce b as m?

Comment: Surely that is pronouncing _m_ as _b_? It's usually thought of as the way you speak when you have a cold in the head (a blocked nose).

Comment: I think there is a clue to the speaker's accent in *ex. I will wake them up from their naps. > aiwoweiktheba^from* The speaker uses a "dark L" in "will". The rest of the transliteration sounds somewhat nasal. So to answer your question: "Probably and in some accents, but it is not standard."

Comment: @KateBunting I just looked up on the blocked nose and a nasal problem real quick and found that it kind of makes sense. I myself repeated the sentence to get to the point where I notice the subtle difference between [m] and [b], feeling (or perhaps _trying_ to feel) my nose vibrated a little bit while speaking. For conversations, this is quite tricky to me though. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Greybeard I've never heard of the dark L before. I looked up for it and the images of it gave me an idea of understanding how both [m] and [b] work altogether and sound like. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I seem to remember the classic sentence in 'cold-English' in comics is 'Thag you very buch'.

Answer (score 0):

it’s possible that the speakers words just slurred together. There are instances where a b is silent when paired with an m like in the words “thumb” or “lamb” but in the example you provided it should just be pronounced with an m.

Comment: I know this case that I provided seems to be an exemption, and now I got to know this is not a standard way of pronouncing m, though it sounds like b. Thanks for your answer!